# How can i change the runtime version of .Net Framework

Tags: .net, dll

I am new to .Net Framework and I don't know how to change the run time version.
I am trying to call a DLL file using JNI(Proxygen).
After hitting the proxygen command I am getting error as "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded".
I have installed .Net Framework 4.8 which is the latest version still I am facing the above issue.
The DLL target framework is version 4.
How Can I change the .Net Runtime version?

Comment: Your installed system .Net Framework won't matter here if the Proxygen software version you are using does not support the .Net Framework version of your target DLL.

Comment: Hi Crashmstr, I am using the latest jni4net proxygen which is 0.8.8 in their official website and the target framework of the dll is 4.0.

Comment: I just replaced the system.runtime dll with the one which was available in the project and my issue got resolved.